# Como pesquisar por parametros

Tags: angularjs, typescript, filter, services

Estou tentando fazer uma busca por parametros, onde o usuario informa 3 parametros e pesquisa isso, segue como estou tentando fazer

```
FindByRdo(numero: number, ano: number, objeto: Objeto) {
    return find(this.http, `${this.endpoint}`);
  }
```

porem, ao passar para o meu componente burro, ele me da erro, alguem sabe me dizer o porque?

Comment: Imagine que gostaria de ajudar alguém, porém só recebesse essas informações. Qual seria sua sugestão?

Answer (score 1):

Quando desejo fazer uma consulta por `query params`, utilizo o seguinte código.

```
  getMedicos(especialidade): Observable<Medico[]> {
    return this.http.get<Medico[]>(this.medicoUrl, {
       params: {
        'especialidade': especialidade
      }
    })
      .pipe(
        catchError(this.handleError<Medico[]>('getMedicos', []))
      )
  }
```

Em meu exemplo estou consultando o endpoint:

```
private medicoUrl = 'http://localhost:8000/medicos/';
```

Porém o endpoint final executando pela aplicação será:

```
http://localhost:8000/medicos/?especialidade=clinico
```

Desta forma imagino que no seu caso seria algo como 3 `query params`, logo no seu exemplo seria algo como:

```
FindByRdo(numero: number, ano: number, objeto: Objeto) {
    return this.http.get(`${this.endpoint}`, {
                params: {
                         'numero':numero, 
                         'ano': ano,
                         'objeto':  o });
  }
```

Repare que em meu exemplo utilizei o `http method` GET. Não ficou claro qual foi o `http method` que utilizou.

Comment: Sensacional, muito obrigada pela ajuda e peço desculpas por fornecer poucas informações